# how to update inputs with the same name in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

so let's say

> I have 2 tables, #1st table is material and #2nd table is Stocks.
>   in Material table contains id_material and material_name.
>   in Stocks table contains the same id: id_material and material_name.
>   each table have the same data.
>
> i want to edit data input for each tables, but i only need to edit from #1st table (ex:id_material) and #2nd table edited automatically. 
>   this my model. what do i need to add for the codes

```
public function get_data_material($where = ""){
     $data_data_material = $this->db->query("select * from data_material ".$where." order by kode_material desc");
     return $data_data_material;
}
```

my controller

```
public function edit_data($kode_material)
{
     $data_material = $this->model_material->get_data_material("where kode_material ='$kode_material'");

     foreach($data_material->result_array()as $row){
        $kode_material  = $row['kode_material'];
        $nama_material  = $row['nama_material'];
        $warna_material = $row['warna_material'];
     }

     $data['kode_material'] = $kode_material;
     $data['nama_material']     = $nama_material;
     $data['warna_material']    = $warna_material;

     $this->load->view('datamaster/tabel_material/v_edit_material', $data);
}
```

I tried googling this and nothing is coming up. 
is there any way I can do this?

Comment: well you need an update query for starters, and don't forget the primary key of course, you'll need it

Comment: can you explain it little more specific?

Comment: I think you just need to put the foreign key and update the data according to the primary key of first table.

Comment: you have to show your model. or just show your SQL update attempt